# Is union of a countable set of Tarski-finite sets countable in ZF? Reference request.

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

This is a reference request  on the consistency, or not, with ZF, of "There exists a countable set $S$ of Tarski-finite sets such that  $\cup S$ is not countable." Only this....NOT about AC, Dependent Choice,Countable Choice, etc.

Comment: How could a paper proving this *not* be about AC?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I read that as emphasizing that the question is just over ZF - not ZFC, ZF+DC, ZF+CC, etc.

Comment: @Noah: since all these assumptions clearly imply this situation is impossible, that's a strange reading of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is consistent that there exists a countable collection of two-element sets has uncountable union, hence the answer to your question is: yes, this is consistent.

As a reference, I will give [this paper](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/119630/CommentatMathUnivCarolRetro_47-2006-4_15.pdf), which proves that such a collection of pairs exist. Indeed,these pairs satisfy quite a bit more properties, see Definition 3 and Proposition 18.

Comment: Thank you. A commenter to my A. to Q.  1602566 insisted that you can prove that a countable union of finite sets is countable without AC, which I knew is wrong. I posted your link in a comment there.